# Javascript .closest()/.next()/.siblings() method to remove row in table <tr> not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried several solution found on stackoverflow and cannot make it work. Here is my html code:

```
<div class "rowdiv">
    <tr>
        <td width="5%">
            <div class='text-center'> <a href="" onclick="deleteLine(this)" id="l_<%=k%>"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>

            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="45%">
            <input class="form-control input-sm" id="description_<%=k%>" placeholder="Description" value="<%= @hash[k][0] %>">
        </td>
        <td width="10%">
            <select class="form-control input-sm" data-rule-required="true" id="unit_<%=k%>" name="validation_select">
                <option></option>
                <option>ml</option>
                <option>m2</option>
                <option>u</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td width="5%">
            <div class='text-center'>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="qte_<%=k%>" placeholder="Qte" value="<%= @hash[k][1] %>" onchange="priceUpdate(<%=k%>)">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="20%">
            <div class='text-right'>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm text-right" placeholder="PUHT" value="<%= @hash[k][2] %>" id="puht_<%=k%>" onchange="priceUpdate(<%=k%>)"> <span class="input-group-addon">
                                              E
                                            </span>

                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="15%">
            <div class='text-right' id="montant_<%=k%>">
                <%=@ hash[k][2]*@hash[k][1] %>e</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

And I try to delete the whole tr group when clicking on the  tag at the beginning with the function deleteLine(this). Here is the JS script:

```
function deleteLine(item){
item
i2=item.closest('tr');
i2.remove();
}
```

So item works well and is my  tag component but for i2 it gives me an Uncaught TypeError : undefined is not a function.
I have tried unsuccessfully (same error as above) the following different code for i2:

```
i2=item.closest('.rowdiv').find('tr');
i2=item.siblings('tr');
i2=item.next('tr');
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: `item` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object.

Comment: You should also probably use `parent` instead of `closest`. They are very similar but this page explains the difference: http://api.jquery.com/closest/#entry-longdesc.

Comment: @pseudosavant `parent` is a `td` , won't work. Can use `parents` but then you have to make sure there aren't any same tags further up the tree. `closest` is best in my mind

Comment: @charlietfl Actually, `parent` will traverse all the way up to the document root until it finds an element that matches the given selector. From the jQuery docs: "the .parent() method allows us to search through the *parents*" http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: @pseudosavant: Nope, you misunderstood the docs. The "parents" being referred to are the individual parent element of each in the set. Not multiple parents (better referred to as ancestors) of a single element.

Comment: @pseudosavant sorry but an element can only have one parent.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode

Comment: @cookiemonster I stand corrected. I tried it out and you are correct. http://jsbin.com/tuhij/1/edit I thought `.parent('selector')` was the same as `.parents('selector').first()' but that is clearly not the case.

Comment: @charlietfl I know DOM elements only have on parent element. We weren't strictly speaking about the DOM but about DOM traversal using jQuery though.

Comment: @pseudosavant all's well, was just trying to keep invalid information from propagating. `parent()` is just not the right method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`item` is a dom element not a jQuery object

You need to wrap it in `$()` to use jQuery methods

```
function deleteLine(item){
    $(item).closest('tr').remove();    
}
```

Comment: Thanks! By the way, what is the exact difference between $ and document.getElementById?

Comment: the second returns a dom element, that dom element can then be used by jQuery by turning it into a jQuery object

Comment: Thanks, I finally get this!